# Datefilter in leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, filter, date, datetime, feature-filter

How do I filter data by date. If I want to filter, I can see the old filtering too. The layers are stacked on top of each other. How do I get the current date range.

```
<div id="time-ranges" class="leaflet-bar">
    <form action="#" id="form">
      <label for="from">
        From
        <input id="from" type="date" value="1998-07-01" name="from">
      </label>
      <label for="to">
        To
        <input  id="to" type="date" value= "2019-12-19" name="to">
      </label>
      <input id = "sub" type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
  </div>
$("#form").submit(function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();   
        var inf = L.geoJSON(inf_st,{
            filter: function (feature, layer) {

                return new Date(feature.properties.fest_datum) >= new Date(document.getElementById("from").value) && new Date(feature.properties.fest_datum) <= new Date(document.getElementById("to").value); 

            }

        }).addTo(map);

    });
```

Comment: How i remove existing GeoJSON layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at docs for filter option of `L.geoJSON` object (https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#geojson), you will see the following note: *Note: dynamically changing the filter option will have effect only on newly added data. It will not re-evaluate already included features.* This means that each time you change filter conditions, you have to remove existing GeoJSON layer and add it again.

In your case put layer variable `inf` outside `$("#form").submit` function and initially set to `null` value. Then check it's value and if it's not `null`, remove layer with `removeLayer` method.

Your code could look something like this:

```
var inf = null;

$("#form").submit(function(e){  
  e.preventDefault();   
  if (inf != null) map.removeLayer(inf);
  inf = L.geoJSON(inf_st,{
    filter: function (feature, layer) {
      return new Date(feature.properties.fest_datum) >= new Date(document.getElementById("from").value) && new Date(feature.properties.fest_datum) <= new Date(document.getElementById("to").value); 
    }
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

*Remark:* This is basic Leaflet functionality, so reading docs can help.